# Facebook Wall Photos albums.. bug?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

using the graph api me/albums method, I get two "Wall Photos" album entries.. with different types (normal, wall)

My understanding is: "wall" is used to store the wall photo posts and "normal" to store the photos posted in a friend's wall..

Question: Why is the type normal? shouldn't be something different to understand the album has not been actually created by the user? like other automatically created albums.. (profile, mobile, wall)

Every posts on the "normal" Wall Photos album are not really visible, because the album is not accessible from the UI.. so I need a way to filter this album out from the list of usable albums, but I would rather find a better way instead of verifying the name of the album..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am finding this same issue - and now I'm getting graph API errors on it. Did you ever find a solution?